# SAP connectvitiy through JDBC in android

Tags: android

I am trying to connect to SAP database through JDBC connection. I am getting following exception

> com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: Cannot connect to db url

But If I try the same code as normal java application it's working fine. And I am using emulator for testing.

Please suggest me the solution

Comment: My first guess would be that you forgot to give your application the INTERNET permission...

Answer (score 0):

> com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: Cannot connect to db url

This exception occur when there is wrong in your url which connect to database server. Check it name and port no and must have permission of internet in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I am using the correct url only. There is no error in that. The same code is working in java. But not in android. I declared internet permission in manifest also. But still facing the problem.

Comment: Ya I have added it to libs folder. And imported the same in project properties also.

Comment: @saran whatever type of driver you are using either type1, 2, 3, 4. Check it whether database url is correct. and also check it on your system whether database server is accessible or not by using parameter whichever you are using.

Comment: @saran Have you tried my last comment. Is it solved your problem.?